# lua: how to bind my function to the io library

Tags: lua

I wrote a lua function **write_json** which translates lua table into json text.
Is it possible to bind the function with the io library, so that I can use it like this:

```
    mytable = {name="Jack", age="22", score=[12,33,55,66]}

    f = io.open("score.json", "wb")
    f:write_json(mytable) -- call my function here.
    f:close()
```

Comment: Try `io.write_json = whatever`, but I don't recommend messing with builtins.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo in this way, how can i access the file object in "write_json". is there a "self" pointer?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo - It does not work.

Answer (score 3):

You need access to the `__index` table of the metatable for file objects and put your new methods there:

```
local metatable = getmetatable( io.stdout )
local indextable = metatable.__index
indextable.write_json = function( file, tab )
  -- ...
end
```

There is another way: The C API function `luaL_newmetatable` stores the metatable for file objects in the registry under the key `"FILE*"`, so the following will also work (but requires the debug library):

```
local metatable = debug.getregistry()["FILE*"]
local indextable = metatable.__index
-- ...
```

There is yet another (more hackish) way: All Lua versions I tested (PUC-Rio Lua 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, and LuaJIT) set the `__index` field of the metatable to the metatable itself, so you can get at the `__index` table like that:

```
local indextable = io.stdout.__index
```

The best way is probably the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the object returned by `io.open` is `userdata`, which I believe cannot be monkey-patched due to its unique nature.

Comment: i found this, [link](http://source.contextgarden.net/l-io.lua) . same idea, but it has to pass a file object as api's first parameter. not exactly the binding i am expecting.